# react почему не изменяет setState значение

Tags: reactjs

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: 1
    } 
    
  }



render(){
  const abs = ()=>this.setState({date:'2'})
  return (
    <div>fffff {abs()}</div>
  )
}
}


   ReactDOM.render(
      <Clock />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в render нельзя вызывать setState.

Comment: получается можно только так componentWillMount() {
  this.setState({date:'2'});
} ?

Comment: или как можно с переданной функцией?

Comment: лучше Did, чем Will.

Comment: а почему так не работает?     class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: 1
    } 
    
  }

 aff =() =>{
  this.setState({date:'2'})
 
}


render(){
 
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>this.setState({date:'2'})}>1</button>
      fffff {aff}{this.state.date}</div>
  )
}
}

Comment: если вынести за рендер функцию?

Comment: У тебя в консоли браузера написано, почему: `Uncaught ReferenceError: aff is not defined`

Comment: ReferenceError: aff is not defined

Comment: а почему не определена если я ее вызываю, не могу догнать

Comment: 1. потому что this. 2. всё равно не заработает.

Comment: ладно спасибо буду разбираться!

Answer (score 1):

Потому что как я понял вот мой пример

[Мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1126666/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-react-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-render-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5-return-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Экспериментировав я пришёл к тому что setState мало того что обновляет метод render так она ещё даёт команду react изменять свойства в разделе return. Без вызова этого метода можно добиться чтобы метод render обновлялся, а значит проверялось изменение некоторых свойств, но хоть они и поменяли состояние изменение не вносятся именно в раздел return.

Ваш же случай как я понимаю, ошибка заключается в том что работает отрабатывает render потом встречается setState которая обновляет снова render и так по кругу. Бесконечный цикл. Вот и ошибка