# Почему React не меняет состояние в методе render в разделе return без использования setState?

Tags: reactjs

Изучая React зашёл немного в тупик. Почему не происходит обновления куска кода в методе render при создании компонента. Обновление метода происходит и изменяется состояние свойств и переменных, но React не хочет менять их в разделе return, без использования setState. Почему это происходит?

```
class Input extends React.Component{

flags = {check: false}
method({target}){
    this.flags.check = !this.flags.check //меняем свою переменную
    this.setState({})//рабочий вариант
    //this.render() //обновляет, но не передаёт в методе render в return.

}
```

Можно и так

```
state = {check: false}
   method({target}){
   this.setState({check: target.checked})

}
```

```
render(){
    let messege;
    console.dir(this);//меняется состояние
    if(this.flags.check)
        messege = 'выбран';
    else
        messege = 'не выбран';
    console.dir(messege);
    return (
        <div>
            <input id='check' type="checkbox" onChange={this.method.bind(this)}/>
            <p>Чекбокс {messege}</p>
        </div> 
    )
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Input name='Евгений Ваганович'>Какой-то текст</Input>,
    document.querySelector('form')
)
```

```
class Input extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)

}
state = {messege: localStorage.getItem('messege') || 'не выбран'}
method = function({target}){

    let ch = (target.checked) ? 'выбран' : 'не выбран';
    this.setState({messege: ch})

    localStorage.setItem('messege', ch)
    localStorage.setItem('check', target.checked)

}.bind(this) //замена такого подхода this.method.bind(this) 

render(){
    console.dir(this);
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.method} defaultChecked={localStorage.getItem('check')}/>
            <p>Чекбокс {this.state.flags}</p>
        </div> 
    )
}
```

}

Прочитал статью где говорят что bind создаёт новую функцию при каждом запросе где-то в недрах кода и не очищает память по всей видимости и указывать в событии 
this.method1.bind(this) не лучшая затея видимо. Предлагают использовать передачу контекста в конструкторе, но если посмотреть мы храним метод в **proto** и к тому же создаём новый метод на 0 уровне скажем так передав ему копию метода с контекстом. Разве не лучше просто создать метод на 0 уровне и передать контекст?

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.newMethod = this.method1.bind(this)
    this.newMethod1 = function(){ console.dir(this) }.bind(this)//как мне кажется лучший вариант 

}
//или за пределами одно и то же
newMethod1 = function(){ console.dir(this) }.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы компонент обновился либо должен обновиться его состояние либо пропсы иначе никак.

Так писать обновления чего либо в React-е не советую

```
let messege;
if(this.flags.check)
   messege = 'выбран';
else
   messege = 'не выбран';
```

Если хотите чтобы ваш компонент работал как надо и обновлялся  когда надо обновляйте все через `state` вот так

```
this.setState({message: 'Выбран'});
```

и держите метод `render` чистым.

Правильный вариант будет вот так [**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-violet-31zxj?file=/src/App.js:111-491)

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flags: false
    };
  }

  method() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      flags: !state.flags
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input id="check" type="checkbox" onChange={this.method.bind(this)} />
        <p>Чекбокс {this.state.flags ? "выбран" : "не выбран"}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: А я пробовал вывести <p>Чекбокс {this.state.check}</p> и ничего не происходило, поэтому меня это сбило с толку я подозревал что наверно булево значение не выводит, но не пробовал. Действительно строка выводит. </n> вы имели виду так?   state = {check: 'не выбран'}
    method({target}){
        let ch = (target.checked) ? 'выбран' : 'не выбран';
        this.setState({check: ch})
       
    }

Comment: @SinGlEBW у вас в стейте нету этого свойства `check`.Как вы хотите получить его?

Comment: я писал state = {check: false}   и пробовал {this.state.check} положительного результата не было т.к. это булево. Это потом я начал добавлять свой объект

Comment: @SinGlEBW обновил ответ.Добавил рабочий вариант.

Comment: А разве не требуется использовать babel? Я вообще пишу в файле формата jsx подключив через CDN React, через Gulp настроил babel конвертирую в ES5 и ужимаю через uglify, подключив файл ужатый в index.html. Не знаю насколько правильный подход.

Comment: @SinGlEBW Лучше используйте утилиту `create-react-app` для быстрого создание приложения.И уже тренируйтесь на нем.Если ответ решил вашу проблему примите его нажав на галочку рядом с  ним.